# Regex Validator allowing letters when it shouldn't - VAB

Tags: regex, validation, enterprise-library

I'm doing the validation through configuration files.
But, RegexValidator does not work properly.

This Validator not disciplined even to unknown regular expression!!

For example, if I add a RegexValidator to field with regular expression `\d`, It allow also Letters. it validate only first Character.
Also, if I set more than 15 Characters the validation fails.

Do you know about this problem?

---

Thanks, it really helps things work better!
But I still have a problem if I put more than 15 numbers, validation fails, even though I write a format: `^(\d{1,20})$`
Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: Until proven otherwise (say, by some actual code/regex samples) I bet the bug is not on RegexValidator's side. Please edit your question and tell us what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what your problems is but i suspect that it can be solved by using Regex Anchors. You can read more about them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

An example of there use would be as follows;

```
'\d' true if there is any digit anywhere in the test string
'^\d$' true if the string ONLY contains a single digit
'^\d*$' true if the string ONLY contains 0 or more digits
'^\d+$' true if the string ONLY contains 1 or more digits
'^\d{5}$' true if the string ONLY contains exactly 5 digits (i.e. a zip code)
```

Hope this helps guide you in the correct direction.